# Solstheim: citizens of Raven Rock are attacking me without reason

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'll fast travel from Skyrim to Solstheim and as soon as I arrive, I'm being attacked by the Redoran guards. I haven't committed any crimes there, and I have no bounty.

I saw a post when looking for answers, posted by AJPerez, and answered by the same person, to punch a non guard NPC and then you'll be able to pay the bounty, well I tried that, but I'm not even getting a bounty. I don't know what else I could do so I would like some advice.

Comment: If you found another question asking the same thing, and the answer does not work, it still constitutes a duplicate, im afraid. Perhaps you could link the question? With more rep, you can push for an alternate answer, but theres little a new user can really do.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to try is to reset Solstheim by resting for at least 30 days from outside of that area.

[Respawn Schedule](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawn#Schedule)

The town may still be loaded even if you go outside, so the best way is to go to another location as far away from Solstheim as possible.  I'm not 100% sure whether DLC contents reset if you rest inside the vanilla world map.